# About Mongo Group by where arr.length>0

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Just assume following data:

```
{_id:1,hotelcode:a,availdates:["2020-01-02","2020-02-03"]}
{_id:2,hotelcode:a,availdates:["2020-02-03"]}
{_id:3,hotelcode:b,availdates:[]}
{_id:4,hotelcode:b,availdates:["2020-01-02"]}
{_id:5,hotelcode:c,availdates:["2020-01-02","2020-02-03"]}
```

I wanna achieve:

```
select hotelcode,count(hotelcode) from table group by hotelcode where availdates.length>0
```

What should I do?
I tried:

```
db.getCollection('spl_rate_27').aggregate([
{$project:{
    adlength:{$size:"$avail_dates"}}
},
{$match:{adlength:{$gt:1}}},
{$group:{_id:{hotelcode:"$hotel_code"},total:{$sum:1}}}
```

])

But I got :

```
{
"_id" : {
    "hotelcode" : null
},
"total" : 99999,0
}
```

It seems something was wrong...But I can't find it out....

Comment: Get rid of $project and in $match use $size operator.

Comment: I tried this: `db.getCollection('table').aggregate([
    {$match:{"availdates":{$size:{$gt:0}}}},
    {$group:{_id:{hotelcode:"$hotel_code"},total:{$sum:1}}}
])`  but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like following, first get the objects whose `availdates` is greater than 0

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: "$availdates"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$hotelcode",
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      hotelcode: "$_id",
      total: 1
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3t8TLI3dQjx)

Comment: That's awesome! I think the reason why my script doesn't work is that I didn't use `$expr` to wrap my `$gt`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can change.

1. Instead of `$project` use `$addFields` - `project` restricts fields, `addFields` adds field to the document
2. Then use `$gte` in the query as you need  `>0`.

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R8hGEcyqLHM)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      adlength: {
        $size: "$availdates" //misspelled
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      adlength: {
        $gte: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        hotelcode: "$hotelcode" //misspelled
      },
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer? Is there any difference between `addFields`and  just set the  `{$project: hotelcode:1 } `? They looks the same...

Comment: Project sends what you add to the next stage.

Answer (score 0):

Well , I got inspiration from @Gibbs' answer. And I changed a bit my script:

```
db.getCollection('table').aggregate([
{$project:{
    hotelcode:1, ##I omit this!!!
    adlength:{$size:"$availdates"}}
},
{$match:{"adlength":{$gt:0}}},
{$group:{_id:{hotelcode:"$hotelcode"},total:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

And it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are expecting.

```
    db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    "availdates": {
      "$gt": "1"
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$hotelcode",
    "records": {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
    },
    "dataCount": {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
})
```

Working demo url : [Mongo Playground URL](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IS9sOoALsUn)